# How to change resolution in 'Raspberry Pi OS' to a custom resolution

Tags: screen-resolution, raspberry-pi4, xserver, xrandr

So I'm trying to implement the following resolution: *1920x127*

What I have tried so far:

**Option 1-**

Added the following to  `/boo/config.txt` file :

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_cvt=1920 127 60
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=8
```

Following the Raspberry Pi documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

This doesn't sets the resolution to *1920x127*. But if I use for example *1920x1080* it does change the resolution accordingly.
So this process works but not for my current need.

**Option 2-**

Added the following to `/boot/cmdline.txt` file:

```
video=HDMI-A-1:1920x127M@60
```

So the file looks like this:

```
console=serial0,115200 video=HDMI-A-1:1920x127M@60 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=156bada3-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

And just as the first solution it doesn't work with *1920x127* but it does with *1920x1080*.

Now, this solution does not work alone. It needs the following

Create the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/screen-resolution.conf` and paste:

```
Section "Screen"
 Identifier "Screen0"
 Device "Card0"
 SubSection "Display"
 Modes "1920x127"
 EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But still, with *1920x127* the X server goes to *1024x768* but if I set up both files with *1920x1080* the X server ran at *1920x1080*

**End of option 2**

So checking the `xrandr` command I can see that it says:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 7680 x 7680
```

The minimum is 320x200. So the minimum resolution I was able to set was 1920x240.

Now, about the Monitors.

Everything I have tried have been in 2 monitors:

```
1- ViewSonic VX2776
2- Custom made monitor that should support *1920x127*
```

So. Solution 1 and 2 in the Monitor 1 works with resolution *1920x1080* and *1920x240*, it looks stretched but the Monitor shows something.
It does not work with resolution *1920x127. Meaning that it goes to default *1024x768*.

In the Monitor 2, the solution 1 does not work, it always goes to default *1024x768*. But solution 2 it works with *1920x1080* and *1920x320*. Note the "320", because the *1920x240* it works, meaning that the X servers startx at *1920x240* but the monitor indicates "resolution not supported".

I have tried force *1920x127* with xrandr:

```
cvt 1920 127 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x127_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDM-1 1920x127_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x127
```

(Not actual used code, just an example)

And after this, the monitor goes off, like there is no output. And after set the resolution back to the default one, the monitor goes on.

So, basically the question is: How to set up a resolution below the minimum shown from xrandr *320x200*?

Note: The makers of the monitor show to me the monitor working at *1920x127* with their own SBC with a Rock chip on Android.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow but it would have been well-placed on [RaspberryPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) if you posed it as a question to force the resolution on a RPi4 connected to a 4K TV. Option 1 solved my problem. All you would need to do is answer your own question - there's an option for a "self-answer" when you create a question.

Comment: There are some bugs in the listing:
1. Option 1: hdmi_mode=87 instead of hdmi_mode=8

2. xrandr commands should be:
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "1920x127_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "1920x127_60.00"